# Form submit is not working

Tags: php, templates, symfony1, form-submit

I have problem with form submition I am using html5 with symfony 1.1,

**My Code Snippet**

```
<?php echo form_tag('module_name/AcitonName',array('name' =>'abc', 'id'=>'xyz')) ?> 
    <!-- some fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit"  data-theme="b" id="form-sub">
<?php echo '</form>' ?>
```

I have this code in template file, but when ever I submit nothing is happening

Comment: If that's your real code you should change AcitonName to ActionName and make PHP output the ending form tag like <?='</form>'?>

Comment: If you had turn on error reporting, you would have seen the issue right there.

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* [doesn't explain the problem](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help3) enough. You need to elaborate on your input, expected and actual outcomes, or concretise error messages. For example, it would be helpful if you would show the actual HTML output, not only the code that is intended to generate it. And how can you say that nothing is happening? What does that "nothing" look like?

Comment: Can we see the generated html for your form ?

Comment: @Alex : No its not real code I have different module name and action name.

Comment: @j0k : this is the generated code....<form name="abc" id="xyz" method="post" action="/register/ConfirmServices"> <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="c1" value="1" class="validate[required]" /><br><br> <input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="c2" value="1" class="validate[required]" /><br><br>
<!--btn-->
<div class="form_btn">
<input  type="hidden" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" value="a" size="20"  id="Error">
<input  type="hidden" name="reqfrom" value="mobile">
<button type="submit" value="Submit"  data-theme="b" id="form-sub">
</div>
</form>

Comment: @hakre : Nothing means no action is taking place. It is not posting data nor redirecting .

Comment: @somu.web I just pasted your code in a jsfiddle, and everything went fine when I submit it: http://jsfiddle.net/Peqsh/1/ Does the page reload? Any javascript errors?

Comment: @j0k: Ya it works for me if I paste in separate html file, but it is not working in my project and also not page reloading and not javascript errors

Comment: @somu.web well it will be hard to find what's wrong then .. paste the entire html code generated in a jsfiddle or a pastebin, so we can check it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17690/discussion-between-somu-web-and-j0k)

Answer (score 2):

If this is the problem, it's probably you did not echo your `</form>` to the browser. Use

```
<?php echo '</form>'; ?>
```

Comment: sorry I missed typing echo here. I have echo in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a semi-colon:

```
<?php echo '</form>'; ?>
```

If this is just a typo and not the actual problem, what does your opening `<form>` tag look like?

Comment: Semi colon is not needed in this particular case.

Comment: @VettelS: <form name="abc" id="xyz" method="post" action="/module_name/ActionName">.. this is how the opening <form> tag look like in source of the page .